# Query behaviour different from explain plan in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, sql-execution-plan, mongodb-indexes

We have a mongo collection with about 10 million records. There are two indices: `expires_date` and `processing_state`. One of the queries accesses data between two `expires_date (gte and lte)` and `processing_state = 'PROCESSED'`.

The explain plan for the query shows two plans, one with an index scan on `expires_date` and the other on the `processing_state`, but the winning plan is shown to be `expires_date`.

When we run the query,  it takes a lot of time (almost forever) but if we remove the `processing_state` field it completes almost instantaneously.

Also, the `processing_state` field has almost all the 10 million records as `PROCESSED`. Only a handful of records can be in `PENDING` or `FAILED` state. If we specify the `processing_state` other than `PROCESSED` query runs fast.

This behaviour is consistent even if the provided date range has 0 records.

From, the behaviour it seems the query is doing an index scan on `processing_state` instead of `expires_date`, which is againt what explain plan suggests. Any reasons why it should happen.

Comment: It helps if you post your queries too. And, run the `db.collection.getIndexes()` command and list the indexes (other than the `_id`).

Comment: Please post the the results of `.explain("executionStats")`, a sample document and the query.